Why a basis in super dense quantum coding?
In the classical super dense quantum coding scheme of Bennet and Wiesner (1992), the authors start from an element in the Bell base (which consists of $4 = 2^2 = 2 \times 2$ states, in dimension $4$), and then send a message of $2$ classical bits.
The scheme generalizes to qudits using a Bell-kind-of base consisting of $d^2$ states (in dimension $d^2$). But why does one insist on using a basis in the first place ?
Couldn't we send more classical messages (in fact, all classical bit strings of length $d$) through a variant of the scheme where we start from a set of $2^d$ entangled states in dimension $d^2$ which (of course) do not form a basis ?
Would the coding scheme be so much worse given that the states do not form a basis (but still encode all classical bit strings of size $d$ on the other hand) ?

The problem is how are you going to read out the data at the end of the protocol? By using an orthonormal basis, you guarantee that each of the states that you encode into can be distinguished by a measurement. If you use states that overlap each other, for any given measurement, there will be multiple different pieces of information that could have encoded something that would give that measurement. Which one was it? You can't know.

Where exactly is this used in the protocol ? Alice applies one of the Pauli operators on her part of the entangled state, and Bob also applies an operator which sends the Bell state he has received to a classical state. Nowhere orthogonality is used, if I am not mistaken ?

How does Bob "send" the Bell state to a classical state. Either you're talking about measuring in the Bell basis, or you're performing a unitary to convert into the standard basis, and then measuring in that basis (how many classical states have you got?).

Just to be clear (for me): with measuring in the Bell basis, you mean that Bob writes the received state $\alpha$ as a linear combination of Bell states, but since $\alpha$ is one of these states by construction, we know with 100% certainty that he measures one of the Bell states ?

Yes (which only works if you're using an orthonormal basis).
